# How to create a score counter on recyclerView items using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a score counter for rating each item in RecyclerView. I want to rate positive and add 1 score when "+" is pressed and negative when "-" is pressed.
I tried to do this but when I press buttons the number doesn't change.

[image]

this is the data class:

```
data class Surveys(
val surveyName:String,
var countNumber: Int,

)
```

this is my RV adapter:

```
class SurveyAdapter(val changeNumberCallBack: ChangeNumberCallBack) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SurveyAdapter.SurveyViewHolder>() {

val array = arrayOf<String>("A","B","C","D")


inner class SurveyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var surveyName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName)
    val mediaBtn: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaBtn)
    val decreaseBtn: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.decreaseNumber)
    val increaseBtn: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.increaseNumber)
    var surveyNumber: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.countNumber)


    fun surveyItemBind(surveys: Surveys) {
        surveyName.text = surveys.surveyName
        decreaseBtn.setOnClickListener {

            changeNumberCallBack.onDecreaseNumber(surveys)
notifyDataSetChanged()

        }

        increaseBtn.setOnClickListener {

            changeNumberCallBack.onIncreaseNumber(surveys)
notifyItemChanged(position)

        }

        mediaBtn.setOnClickListener {
            changeNumberCallBack.onMediaClick()

        }

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SurveyViewHolder {
    return SurveyViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.survey_item, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = array.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SurveyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.surveyItemBind(Surveys(array[position], 0))
}

interface ChangeNumberCallBack {
    fun onIncreaseNumber(surveys: Surveys)
    fun onDecreaseNumber(surveys: Surveys)
    fun onMediaClick()
}
```

and this is the activity class:

```
class SurveyActivity : AppCompatActivity(),SurveyAdapter.ChangeNumberCallBack {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_survey)

    var surveyRv:RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_rv)
    surveyRv.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
    surveyRv.adapter = SurveyAdapter(this)

}

override fun onIncreaseNumber(surveys: Surveys) {
    surveys.countNumber++
}

override fun onDecreaseNumber(surveys: Surveys) {
    surveys.countNumber--
}

override fun onMediaClick() {
    startActivity(Intent(this,MediaSurveyActivity::class.java))
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this?
can someone update my code?

Comment: It can quickly be done if you just pass your data-source `surveys` from the `SurveyActvity`. Follow this: 1. Remove `array` and pass `surveys` from the `SurveyActivity`, by using **pass by reference**, in `SurveyAdapter` constructor. 2. Handle the increment and decrement operations in `SurveyActivity` using the callback -- particularly, get the corresponding `survey` using position and update the `countNumber`. Any changes you make in `SurveyActivity` for `surveys` should be reflected the adapter. You need to call `notifiyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged(int)` once you update the count.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but why should array be removed? and by removing it  how to give itemCount and holder to adapter?

Comment: I think what @Jay wrote goes somewhat beyond your question - I believe he meant that you probably would pass the data from the outside of the adapter and you can do it in a similar way to how you pass your callbacks in the adapter constructor. The more important thing to have views updated properly is to call one of the `notify...Changed()` methods - to let `RecyclerView` know that something has changed.

Comment: Yes, the array is my only data, I have nothing else, and array is showing correctly, but the score numbers do not change onclick even though I've called notifyItemChanged(position) or notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter.

Comment: I do not see `notify...` calls in your code - can you update your example?

Comment: Updated, I used both and none works.